# Slideshow stop after 2 loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to set my slider to stop after 2 loops. What's the best way to approach this with the following code I have below? Should I store the length in a variable for counting and set a conditional to see if case is matched and to stop? Any thoughts?

```
var slider = $(".box .slide");
var slideIndex = -1;

function showNextSlide() {
    ++slideIndex;
    slide.eq(slideIndex % slide.length)
        .fadeIn(700)
        .delay(4000)
        .fadeOut(700, showNextSlide);
}

showNextSlide();
```

Comment: call method in a loop!

Comment: @zod, it's a recursive function call

Comment: put an if condition inside method then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably apply a conditional statement in showNextSlide.

```
var numSlides = 123; // define or get the number of slides you have here

function showNextSlide() {
    if (slideIndex < 2* numSlides) {
        ++slideIndex;
        slider.eq(slideIndex % slider.length)
            .fadeIn(700)
            .delay(4000)
            .fadeOut(700, showNextSlide);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo here, you just have to update instances of `slide` to `slider`.

There's no reason to use the `if` statement as proposed by other answers/comments.

```
var slider = $(".box .slide");
var slideIndex = -1;

function showNextSlide() {
    ++slideIndex;
    slider.eq(slideIndex % slider.length)
        .fadeIn(700)
        .delay(4000)
        .fadeOut(700, showNextSlide);
}

showNextSlide();
```

<kbd>[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hzjz3skd/)</kbd>

Comment: Maybe you should specifically mention that he has a typo in the variable, no? (because it took some time to see the diff)

Comment: There's nothing wrong :P just stating own opinion of what it likes :D (+1 for edit)